MLflow Docker build fails on Windows - 'command gcc failed'
I am trying to build a container from an MLFlow hosted model on Windows. Per mlflow instructions, the command looks like:
f"mlflow models build-docker --model-uri {logged_model} --name {container_name}"

This seems to install dependencies successfully but eventually fails with gcc command failed - sudo apt-get install gcc. How would I integrate the fix into this pipeline? Is it expected that docker runs Linux commands while building on Windows (does it run in a VM?), or is there a setting I need to change?
Downloading artifacts: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 1001.27it/s]
2024/04/18 11:08:54 INFO mlflow.models.flavor_backend_registry: Selected backend for flavor 'python_function'
Downloading artifacts: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 9/9 [00:00<00:00, 69.77it/s]
2024/04/18 11:08:55 INFO mlflow.pyfunc.backend: Building docker image with name power_consumption_v1
D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py:219: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.10kB done
#1 DONE 0.1s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.7-slim
#2 DONE 1.2s

#3 [internal] load .dockerignore
#3 transferring context: 2B done
#3 DONE 0.1s

#4 [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11.7-slim@sha256:53d6284a40eae6b625f22870f5faba6c54f2a28db9027408f4dee111f1e885a2
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 124.36MB 5.0s
#5 transferring context: 136.66MB 6.2s done
#5 DONE 6.3s

#6 [2/8] RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nginx
#6 CACHED

#7 [3/8] WORKDIR /opt/mlflow
#7 CACHED

#8 [4/8] RUN pip install mlflow==2.11.3
#8 CACHED

#9 [5/8] COPY model_dir/best_estimator /opt/ml/model
#9 CACHED

#10 [6/8] RUN python -c "from mlflow.models import container as C; C._install_pyfunc_deps('/opt/ml/model', install_mlflow=False, enable_mlserver=False, env_manager='local');"
#10 2.315 Collecting pip==23.3.1
#10 2.315   Obtaining dependency information for pip==23.3.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/6a/453160888fab7c6a432a6e25f8afe6256d0d9f2cbd25971021da6491d899/pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
#10 2.489   Downloading pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
#10 2.847 Collecting setuptools==68.2.2
#10 2.847   Obtaining dependency information for setuptools==68.2.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/26/7945080113158354380a12ce26873dd6c1ebd88d47f5bc24e2c5bb38c16a/setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
#10 2.874   Downloading setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
#10 2.955 Collecting wheel==0.41.2
#10 2.955   Obtaining dependency information for wheel==0.41.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/8b/31273bf66016be6ad22bb7345c37ff350276cfd46e389a0c2ac5da9d9073/wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
#10 2.983   Downloading wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
#10 2.995 Requirement already satisfied: mlflow==2.11.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.11.3)
#10 3.036 Collecting argparse==1.4.0 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 2))
#10 3.037   Obtaining dependency information for argparse==1.4.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/94/3af39d34be01a24a6e65433d19e107099374224905f1e0cc6bbe1fd22a2f/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
#10 3.063   Downloading argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
#10 3.128 Collecting cloudpickle==2.2.1 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 3))
#10 3.129   Obtaining dependency information for cloudpickle==2.2.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/80/44286939ca215e88fa827b2aeb6fa3fd2b4a7af322485c7170d6f9fd96e0/cloudpickle-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
#10 3.155   Downloading cloudpickle-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
#10 3.359 Collecting lz4==4.3.2 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 4))
#10 3.359   Obtaining dependency information for lz4==4.3.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/8f/955d5447392f3ada5274cfe3e3d7058e1c1230711ebdf45b285783bbdfed/lz4-4.3.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
#10 3.387   Downloading lz4-4.3.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
#10 3.407 Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.26.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.26.4)
#10 3.468 Collecting packaging==23.1 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 6))
#10 3.468   Obtaining dependency information for packaging==23.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/c3/57f0601a2d4fe15de7a553c00adbc901425661bf048f2a22dfc500caf121/packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
#10 3.496   Downloading packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
#10 3.818 Collecting pandas==2.1.4 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 7))
#10 3.818   Obtaining dependency information for pandas==2.1.4 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/8c/9ad173c5cd2c7178c84075c02ec37b5d1d53fb1d015f51ea3e623ea9c31c/pandas-2.1.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
#10 3.845   Downloading pandas-2.1.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (18 kB)
#10 3.948 Collecting pathlib==1.0.1 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 8))
#10 3.949   Obtaining dependency information for pathlib==1.0.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/f9/690a8600b93c332de3ab4a344a4ac34f00c8f104917061f779db6a918ed6/pathlib-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
#10 3.979   Downloading pathlib-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
#10 4.198 Collecting psutil==5.9.0 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 9))
#10 4.234   Downloading psutil-5.9.0.tar.gz (478 kB)
#10 4.320      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 478.3/478.3 kB 5.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 4.381   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#10 4.920   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#10 4.926 Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml==6.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 10)) (6.0.1)
#10 5.179 Collecting scikit-learn==1.2.2 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 11))
#10 5.180   Obtaining dependency information for scikit-learn==1.2.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/64/a1e6e92b850b39200c82e3bc54d556b2c634b3904c39ac5cdb10b1c5765f/scikit_learn-1.2.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
#10 5.210   Downloading scikit_learn-1.2.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
#10 5.494 Collecting scipy==1.11.4 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 12))
#10 5.495   Obtaining dependency information for scipy==1.11.4 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/d4/d62ce38ba00dc67d7ec4ec5cc19d36958d8ed70e63778715ad626bcbc796/scipy-1.11.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
#10 5.520   Downloading scipy-1.11.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
#10 5.537      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.4/60.4 kB 4.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 5.634 Collecting xgboost==2.0.3 (from -r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 13))
#10 5.634   Obtaining dependency information for xgboost==2.0.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/eb/496aa2f5d356af4185f770bc76055307f8d1870e11016b10fd779b21769c/xgboost-2.0.3-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
#10 5.669   Downloading xgboost-2.0.3-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.0 kB)
#10 5.768 Requirement already satisfied: click<9,>=7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (8.1.7)
#10 5.778 Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints<1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.4)
#10 5.780 Requirement already satisfied: gitpython<4,>=3.1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.1.43)
#10 5.782 Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<5,>=3.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.25.3)
#10 5.784 Requirement already satisfied: pytz<2025 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (2024.1)
#10 5.786 Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.17.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.31.0)
#10 5.793 Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata!=4.7.0,<8,>=3.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (7.1.0)
#10 5.796 Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse<1,>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.5.0)
#10 5.798 Requirement already satisfied: alembic!=1.10.0,<2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.13.1)
#10 5.800 Requirement already satisfied: docker<8,>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (7.0.0)
#10 5.801 Requirement already satisfied: Flask<4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.3)
#10 5.822 Requirement already satisfied: querystring-parser<2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.2.4)
#10 5.824 Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy<3,>=1.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.0.29)
#10 5.833 Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow<16,>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (15.0.2)
#10 5.836 Requirement already satisfied: markdown<4,>=3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.6)
#10 5.837 Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib<4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.8.4)
#10 5.839 Requirement already satisfied: graphene<4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.3)
#10 5.842 Requirement already satisfied: gunicorn<22 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (21.2.0)
#10 5.844 Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2<4,>=2.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.1.3)
#10 5.930 Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas==2.1.4->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 7)) (2.9.0.post0)
#10 5.932 Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas==2.1.4->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 7)) (2024.1)
#10 5.999 Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from scikit-learn==1.2.2->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 11)) (1.4.0)
#10 6.002 Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from scikit-learn==1.2.2->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 11)) (3.4.0)
#10 6.062 Requirement already satisfied: Mako in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from alembic!=1.10.0,<2->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.3.3)
#10 6.066 Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from alembic!=1.10.0,<2->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.11.0)
#10 6.089 Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.26.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from docker<8,>=4.0.0->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.2.1)
#10 6.105 Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from Flask<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.2)
#10 6.107 Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from Flask<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.2.0)
#10 6.110 Requirement already satisfied: blinker>=1.6.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from Flask<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.7.0)
#10 6.133 Requirement already satisfied: gitdb<5,>=4.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from gitpython<4,>=3.1.9->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.0.11)
#10 6.162 Requirement already satisfied: graphql-core<3.3,>=3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from graphene<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.2.3)
#10 6.164 Requirement already satisfied: graphql-relay<3.3,>=3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from graphene<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.2.0)
#10 6.167 Requirement already satisfied: aniso8601<10,>=8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from graphene<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (9.0.1)
#10 6.199 Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from importlib-metadata!=4.7.0,<8,>=3.7.0->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.18.1)
#10 6.209 Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from Jinja2<4,>=2.11->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.1.5)
#10 6.238 Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.2.1)
#10 6.241 Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.12.1)
#10 6.248 Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.51.0)
#10 6.250 Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.4.5)
#10 6.263 Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (10.3.0)
#10 6.265 Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.1.2)
#10 6.289 Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas==2.1.4->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.16.0)
#10 6.315 Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.17.3->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.3.2)
#10 6.317 Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.17.3->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.7)
#10 6.321 Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.17.3->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (2024.2.2)
#10 6.362 Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from sqlalchemy<3,>=1.4.0->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.3)
#10 6.487 Requirement already satisfied: smmap<6,>=3.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from gitdb<5,>=4.0.1->gitpython<4,>=3.1.9->mlflow==2.11.3->-r /opt/ml/model/requirements.txt (line 1)) (5.0.1)
#10 6.674 Downloading pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
#10 6.799    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 17.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 6.826 Downloading setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (807 kB)
#10 6.873    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 807.9/807.9 kB 18.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 6.901 Downloading wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
#10 6.918    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 64.8/64.8 kB 4.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 6.943 Downloading argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
#10 6.976 Downloading cloudpickle-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
#10 7.010 Downloading lz4-4.3.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
#10 7.103    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.3/1.3 MB 14.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 7.128 Downloading packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
#10 7.145    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 48.9/48.9 kB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 7.173 Downloading pandas-2.1.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.2 MB)
#10 7.718    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.2/12.2 MB 24.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 7.743 Downloading pathlib-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
#10 7.776 Downloading scikit_learn-1.2.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (9.6 MB)
#10 8.197    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9.6/9.6 MB 22.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 8.222 Downloading scipy-1.11.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (36.4 MB)
#10 9.866    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 36.4/36.4 MB 20.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 9.898 Downloading xgboost-2.0.3-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (297.1 MB)
#10 25.61    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 297.1/297.1 MB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 26.62 Building wheels for collected packages: psutil
#10 26.63   Building wheel for psutil (setup.py): started
#10 27.03   Building wheel for psutil (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#10 27.08   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 27.08
#10 27.08   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
#10 27.08   │ exit code: 1
#10 27.08   ╰─> [43 lines of output]
#10 27.08       running bdist_wheel
#10 27.08       running build
#10 27.08       running build_py
#10 27.08       creating build
#10 27.08       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
#10 27.08       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_memleaks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/tests
#10 27.08       running build_ext
#10 27.08       building 'psutil._psutil_linux' extension
#10 27.08       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
#10 27.08       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil
#10 27.08       gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=590 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -DPSUTIL_ETHTOOL_MISSING_TYPES=1 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/psutil/_psutil_common.o
#10 27.08       C compiler or Python headers are not installed on this system. Try to run:
#10 27.08       sudo apt-get install gcc python3-dev
#10 27.08       error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
#10 27.08       [end of output]
#10 27.08
#10 27.08   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#10 27.08   ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
#10 27.08   Running setup.py clean for psutil
#10 27.41 Failed to build psutil
#10 27.41 ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
#10 27.51
#10 27.51 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.0
#10 27.51 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
#10 27.78 Traceback (most recent call last):
#10 27.78   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#10 27.78   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/models/container/__init__.py", line 92, in _install_pyfunc_deps
#10 27.78     activate_cmd = _install_model_dependencies_to_env(model_path, env_manager) if model_path else []
#10 27.78                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#10 27.78   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/models/container/__init__.py", line 144, in _install_model_dependencies_to_env
#10 27.78     raise Exception("Failed to install model dependencies.")
#10 27.78 Exception: Failed to install model dependencies.
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c python -c \"from mlflow.models import container as C; C._install_pyfunc_deps('/opt/ml/model', install_mlflow=False, enable_mlserver=False, env_manager='local');\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [6/8] RUN python -c "from mlflow.models import container as C; C._install_pyfunc_deps('/opt/ml/model', install_mlflow=False, enable_mlserver=False, env_manager='local');":
27.51 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.0
27.51 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
27.78 Traceback (most recent call last):
27.78   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
27.78   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/models/container/__init__.py", line 92, in _install_pyfunc_deps
27.78     activate_cmd = _install_model_dependencies_to_env(model_path, env_manager) if model_path else []
27.78                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
27.78   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/models/container/__init__.py", line 144, in _install_model_dependencies_to_env
27.78     raise Exception("Failed to install model dependencies.")
27.78 Exception: Failed to install model dependencies.
------
Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  13 |     # Copy model to image and install dependencies
  14 |     COPY model_dir/best_estimator /opt/ml/model
  15 | >>> RUN python -c "from mlflow.models import container as C; C._install_pyfunc_deps('/opt/ml/model', install_mlflow=False, enable_mlserver=False, env_manager='local');"
  16 |
  17 |     ENV MLFLOW_DISABLE_ENV_CREATION=True
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python -c \"from mlflow.models import container as C; C._install_pyfunc_deps('/opt/ml/model', install_mlflow=False, enable_mlserver=False, env_manager='local');\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\cli.py", line 274, in build_docker
    python_api.build_docker(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\python_api.py", line 79, in build_docker
    get_flavor_backend(model_uri, docker_build=True, env_manager=env_manager).build_image(
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\mlflow\pyfunc\backend.py", line 359, in build_image
    docker_utils.build_image_from_context(context_dir=cwd, image_name=image_name)
  File "D:\Programs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\docker_utils.py", line 235, in build_image_from_context
    raise RuntimeError("Docker build failed.")
RuntimeError: Docker build failed.


I have arrived at the following solution which seems to be required for any realistic build out of MLflow but is not documented on its forums or any other forum that I've seen. The suggested build command fails to install gcc during the build process, and fails to build a pip wheel for psutils:
mlflow models build-docker --model-uri "runs:/some-run-uuid/my-model" --name "my-image-name"

Instead, it is better to have mlflow generate a dockerfile, edit it, and then build separately:
run_command(f"mlflow models generate-dockerfile --model-uri {logged_model} --output-directory {model_dir}")
    
with open(model_dir / 'Dockerfile', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for ind, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends '):
            lines[ind] = line.split('\n')[0] + ' -y gcc g++\n'
    with open(model_dir / 'Dockerfile', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
    
run_command(f"docker build -t {image_name} {model_dir}")


Nice observation.  I see same error, wonder why it is not popping up for everybody.  I want to mention that within python you can call generate_dockerfile, it is not necessary to do the run_command approach.  But your code that revises the Dockerfile itself is slick!

Shouldn't this be consider bug in mlflow's generate_dockerfile?
